# input arrays before concatenate must have the same number of dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, concatenation

I have two arrays like below:

```
ss3 = [[0 1 2 3 4 5]
       [0 1 2 3 4 5]
       [0 1 2 3 4 5]]
ss1 = [[0]
       [0]
       [0]
       [0]
       [0]
       [0]
       [0]
       [0]
       [0]]
```

How do I join them so the output looks like this:

```
s = [[0 1 2 3 4 5][0 1 2 3 4 5][0 1 2 3 4 5][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0]]
```

I tried:

```
s = np.concatenate(ss3,ss1,axis=0)
```

But keep getting the error:

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Comment: Well, yeah, these arrays cannot be concatenated, precisely because of the reason the error message provides

Comment: Is there another way I can join them?

Comment: I don't think so: "all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly". Anyway, what would be the shape of the matrix you want to create? It'll have some kind of uninitialized "holes" in it, which NumPy doesn't allow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they're just arrays you can just use:

```
ss3 = [[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5],[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]]
ss1 = [[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]

merged = ss3+ss1
```

Which gives:

```
[[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]]
```

Comment: Thanks! But if my arrays are actually of size (3,6) and (9,1) how do I reshape them to be flat to add them?

Comment: Can you give an example of how you defined the input? I would have thought the examples are of size (3,6) and (9,1) already.

Comment: I edited my question to show how the arrays are initially. Sorry, I didn't realize they were shaped like that initially in my code.

Comment: How they're displayed shouldn't make a difference. Are you defining the arrays in some different way, like with numpy? The example in your question isn't valid python without the commas.